# Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in

Tags: php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $data_missing = array();

    if(empty($_POST['first_name'])){

        // Adds name to array
        $data_missing[] = 'First Name';

    } else {

        // Trim white space from the name and store the name
        $f_name = trim($_POST['first_name']);

    }

    if(empty($_POST['last_name'])){

        // Adds name to array
        $data_missing[] = 'Last Name';

    } else{

        // Trim white space from the name and store the name
        $l_name = trim($_POST['last_name']);

    }

    if(empty($_POST['email'])){

        // Adds name to array
        $data_missing[] = 'Email';

    } else {

        // Trim white space from the name and store the name
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);

    }



    if(empty($_POST['birth_date'])){

        // Adds name to array
        $data_missing[] = 'Birth Date';

    } else {

        // Trim white space from the name and store the name
        $b_date = trim($_POST['birth_date']);

    }

    if(empty($_POST['sex'])){

        // Adds name to array
        $data_missing[] = 'Sex';

    } else {

        // Trim white space from the name and store the name
        $sex = trim($_POST['sex']);

    }


    if(empty($data_missing)){

        require_once('database.php');

        $query = "INSERT INTO etable (first_name, last_name, email,
         birth_date, sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?)";

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $f_name,
                               $l_name, $email, $b_date,
                               $sex);

        mysqli_stmt_execute();

        $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows();

        if($affected_rows == 1){

            echo 'Student Entered';

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

            mysqli_close($dbc);

        } else {

            echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
            echo mysqli_error($dbc);

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

            mysqli_close($dbc);

        }

    } else {

        echo 'You need to enter the following data<br />';

        foreach($data_missing as $missing){

            echo "$missing<br />";

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Count your columns.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmm, I wrote pretty much the same thing but as an answer. Did I do wrong?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas No, your answer seems fine. The question though lacks details, such as where those POST arrays come from, being the HTML form and if it's ok or not. The connection is also ambiguous. You/we will just have to see what the OP has say about all this and hasn't even responded to Rizier123's comment. So that in its own right, interprets to an *"give me a magic answer"* type of question. ;-) Wishing you "the green" on this one. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2):

If you're given `boolean`, then it might indicate you're having bad `mysqli_prepare` query. In your case:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO etable (first_name, last_name, email,
         birth_date, sex) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?)";
```

I see that you have chosen 5 columns but written 6 `?` (parameters), thus making this query invalid.

By the way, connection could also cause trouble. Just for sure, you can write:

```
echo mysqli_connect_error();
```

To check if your connection is valid.